# How to set the process name manually before triggering it within shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

How can you set the process name for a process that is to be triggered from a shell script?

For example, if I am going to execute one java class file from a shell script `java <classname>` I need that java process to be seen as `Java_Process_1` when I do `ps ax`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `exec -a Java_Process_1 java <classname>`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, you should accept hwatkins's answer.
Otherwise you can use one of several small programs made exectly for this purpose, like argv0 from http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp.html, runit's chpst (http://smarden.org/runit/chpst.8.html) etc

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need this for Java process, you can take advantage of the JVM's property feature and create a label for your process (that the program itself would be able to see also, if it wanted to):

```
java -Dmy.appid=Java_Process_1 <classname>
```

In general though, `ps` is going to read the value of `/proc/$pid/cmdline` for the command line that it prints, and this value is going to be that of the exact argument vector of the command, null-character delimited.  This means that getting a custom string into there like "Java_Process_1" is going to take some form of non-standard trickery.

Answer (score 0):

On other approach is to create a symbolic link to you java with the name of you application.  ps will use the name of the symbolic link.

ln -s Java_Process_1 /usr/bin/java

Then start you application with

Java_Process_1 -jar ......

Answer (score -1):

You can't. A process needs to exist before **it itself** can modify its argv[0].

Comment: its possible in windows cmd. Eg:- cmd start process_name java javaclass. So is there any wild chance in Unix for the same?

Comment: You're trying to solve the wrong problem the wrong way. What is the top-level problem you want to solve? That said, you could link the java binary under an additional name and then call it using that name.